# Zombie.js testing JS file load

Tags: node.js, zombie.js

I want to make a test for my dynamic token of CSS and JS files.

I am using require.js for Async loading of JS files.

I can see this line in debug mode:

```
Zombie: GET http://localhost:3030/js/main.js?t=0.6705877124331892 => 200
```

but I am not sure how I can write test to check if the file was loaded properly.

Anyone has idea ?